# Flutter for web : Can we use Internationalization?

Tags: flutter, web, internationalization

I develop a web/mobile app with Flutter. Until now, I didn't have any difficulties. But I try to use Internationalization.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

It works on mobile devices (Android). But not for web browser, I tried Chrome and Safari.

Docs says that Internationalization uses local device's preferences.

So, does someone know if it is possible to use Internationalization with Flutter for Web ?

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.19.* you'll be able to access current locale in Flutter. [Here's the related PR](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/18137). It's already available in beta channel and should be present in next stable release.